# Jquery Datatables drag and drop without change row Id

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using: `jquery.dataTables.js` from: https://datatables.net

I am using official **RowReorder** plugin and it is working perfectly right now.

**What I want to do is**: make the order number not change.

Right now if I move the columns the number change in the order column.

So what I would like to is this number be the same as before understand?

If I move row 3 to the top one the number still be 3 , right now is changing for 1.

So in the end I just want drag a drop without change the order numbers.

Is that possible?

html:

```
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>order</th>
        <th>name</th>
         <th>country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    rowReorder: {
       dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [
      {
         data: 'order'
      },{
         data: 'name'
      },{
         data: 'place'
    }]
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/15/

Comment: is the order number   an attribute of RowReorder? if so you can make you own ronnumber attriute and use those instead for your own administration

Comment: is not, it is comming from this json: http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2

Comment: sorry what? I am not understand what you saying, I am sorry but I did not anything.

Comment: @Anant I down voted your answer simply because it didn't work as expected, the draggable didn't go up until the end and the value changed.

Comment: @OffirPe'er  according to OP's original post my answer is working perfectly fine. I wish now some-one can give him answer of his both question (original +new-one asked in comment). Just check OP's question

Comment: @Raduken do you mind looking at the answers I gave you to your other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the optimal solution but you could save a copy of the original index in a separate property, for example `orderOrig`, and then display `orderOrig` in a separate column.

```
var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   ajax: {
      url: url,
      dataSrc: function(d){
         $.each(d.data, function(index, item){
            item.orderOrig = item.order;
         });
         return d.data;
      }
   },
   rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
   },
   columns: [
     {
        data: 'order'
     },{
        data: 'orderOrig'
     },{
        data: 'name'
     },{
        data: 'place'
   }]
});
```

See [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/45/) for code and demonstration.

You can also hide the column containing the sequence number, see [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/46/).